# Way to edit style of another webpage within iframe, even superficially?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there any way at all to edit the way a page looks within an iframe? I want to change the color of specific links on, say, a google search within an iframe.

Also, why doesn't the code below work in javascript console when google.com is loaded normally?

```
document.body.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].style.color='red';
```

Comment: The second part probably doesn't work because the first link is an image without text (guessing, didn't check).

Comment: oh. i thought getElementsByTagName gets all of the elements?

Comment: @Joe : by using "[0]" you restrict the operation to the first "a" element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't modify content from another domain with Javascript even through an iFrame. If you want to attempt something like this you could site scrape get all the html elements and then display them on your own page using a server side language (getting around domain restrictions of JavaScript).

Comment: How does one site scrape? And would the content look the same as the original site?

Comment: @joeRocc : to ask how you can fetch server-side the content of another web site, you should ask another precise question, precising what server-side language you're using (PHP, java, Go, etc.). If you cannot run a server-side language, you can't do that.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have javascript access from one frame to another one loaded from a different domain.

For the second question, test this :

```
var test = document.body.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i=0; i<test.length; i++) test[i].style.color="red";
```

The difference with your code is that I change all "a" elements, not just first one.